# Passing parameter on a sub-report with internal parameter visibility option

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with 1 sub-report using the Start Date, End Date, Group, Site and Roll Up parameters.  Roll Up parameter is set to be Internal Parameter visibility.

When the report renders I get an error "Sub Report could not be shown", but when I exclude the Roll Up parameter from the Sub Report parameter it works, but unable to define the default value of roll up parameter in the report subscription.

Comment: describe your scenario. as I am also getting the error and I've tried so many things.

Comment: It is actually setup in the data driven subscription where I have to select certain rollup value.

Comment: no one can give perfect answer, you need to check dataset database rights, if multivalue parameters then check that it is passing proper value or not, if possible look into sql profiler that subreport sp is calling or not, also check hide property on report manager, it must be hide while consuming it on main report, and also check subreporrt datasource. still there can be others but for that I need to have some exact scenario. Try above and let me know.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out :)

Comment: Great to know that you have figured out by yourself. so what was the issue? May I know?